# What type of materials can be used for runway shoulders?

Tags: faa

Instead of paving the shoulders what are the easier solution can be usedwithin FAA regualtions?

Comment: They sometimes put fake grass or polyethene sheets. I do not know about the regulations regarding this though. There was one video where a 747 on takeoff was blowing off the side fake grass sheets probably due to bad installation

Comment: See in 6.3 - Shoulder Material Requirements in [AC-150/5320](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/150-5320-6G-Pavement-Design.pdf)